# Using date and time to create datetime

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database

- Column name : createDate  <--- Type: date  // 2018-01-26
- Column name : createTime  <--- Type: time  // 11:50:30
- Datetime  --> 2018-01-26 11:50:30

I want to print using a select query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server allows you to add two `datetime` values.  So:

```
select cast(createDate as datetime) + cast(createTime as datetime)
```

Unfortunately, you cannot add a `time` to a `date`.  But the type conversion is simple enough.

Comment: You are the best.